# How to update ntpd to the latest version to patch the latest vulnerability?

Tags: server, upgrade, updates, security, ntp

This week [a new attack](http://arstechnica.com/security/2015/10/new-attacks-on-network-time-protocol-can-defeat-https-and-create-chaos/) on the Network Time Protocol Daemon (ntpd) was demonstrated, [see this paper](http://www.cs.bu.edu/~goldbe/papers/NTPattack.pdf). This could potentially wreak havoc with my HTTPS website or other time sensitive services I am running.

According to the article, to remain safe, clients and servers alike should run at least NTP version **4.2.8p4**.

Running `ntpd --version` on my Ubuntu Server 14.04.3 LTS machine gives me `ntpd 4.2.6p5` which is still vulnerable. This is even after running `apt-get update`, `apt-get upgrade` and `apt-get dist-upgrade`.

Apparently I can download the latest version from ntp.org myself. But I am unsure if this will conflict with my existing ntpd install done via `apt-get`. Also they only offer the download via HTTP and their method of ensuring authenticity is by using an MD5 hash checksum... I am looking forward to my NSA backdoored patch. I really wish people would use GPG signatures.

1. Does Ubuntu plan to release a security patch to upgrade ntpd to 4.2.8p4 any time soon? What will be needed to get the fix?
2. If I read the code and assumed the 4.2.8p4 version available for download on the ntp.org website was trustworthy, how can I install that without conflicts?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

1. Install `checkinstall`, read `man checkinstall` and use `checkinstall` to keep track of the files installed.
2. Download, build and install the version of `ntpd` that you need, overwriting Ubuntu's. Check to see that you can `make uninstall` (by reading `Makefile`), or keep track of the files installed.
3. When Ubuntu updates `ntpd` to, or beyond, the desired version, return to the source directory and `make uninstall`. Then `sudo apt-get install --reinstall ntpd` should get you re-synchronized with the official version.

**Note:** I have not tried this, so I may be wrong.

Comment: Great, thanks. The install procedure worked more or less how you said. `wget http://www.eecis.udel.edu/~ntp/ntp_spool/ntp4/ntp-4.2/ntp-4.2.8p4.tar.gz` && `tar xvfz ntp-4.2.8p4.tar.gz` && `cd ntp-4.2.8p4/` && `./configure` && `make` && `make install`. Then `ntpd --version` which showed the new version `ntpd 4.2.8p4`.