# how to update to latest ntp patch 4.2.8p12 on ubuntu 18.04

Tags: updates, ntp, patch

I tried the method here [How to update ntpd to the latest version to patch the latest vulnerability?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/689565/how-to-update-ntpd-to-the-latest-version-to-patch-the-latest-vulnerability/1123104#1123104)

But it failed. Patch 12 has been out for a while now. Does ubuntu plan to have it included in the apt update etc?

If not, could I please be advised of how to update to the latest patch?

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't have the information if Ubuntu / Canonical 18.04 will be updated to 4.2.8p12 ntp.  That would have to be filed with them.

However, you can install it by first downloading the newest version from http://support.ntp.org/bin/view/Main/SoftwareDownloads

Might need to install the build-essential as well for making the files.

```
sudo apt install build-essential
```

Then go to your Downloads folder and extract the file:

```
cd ~/Downloads
tar zxvf ntp-4.2.8p12.tar.gz
```

Go to the newly created folder:

```
cd ntp-4.2.8p12/
```

Now run the `configure`, `make` and `sudo make install`

```
./configure
make
sudo make install
```

The new version should now be installed.  Reboot the system for the changes to take effect.  After it is rebooted you can check for the newest version.

```
$ ntpd --version
ntpd 4.2.8p12@1.3728 Tue Mar  5 03:47:55 UTC 2019 (1)
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: @yi_asb You're welcome!  As I just checked, they are now at 4.2.8p13 and the installation steps would be exactly the same with the exception of the name ending in p13.

Comment: the reason I am doing this is because I am using a security app called Forticlient. It was detecting the ntp vulnerability and referencing this http://support.ntp.org/bin/view/Main/NtpBug2901. Even after upgrading to ntp patch 13, Forticlient is still thinks there's the same issue. Is there a way to wipe ntp and install new with the latest patch? Forticlient may be detecting some old files... thanks

Comment: @yi_asb I am wondering if the Fortclient has an issue detecting the bug?  I did a clean install of the newest NTP on my host by completely removing the old one and building the new one from source and when I ran the Fortclient it gave me the errors of the bug still there.